# trigger click event in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code:

```
$("#tableGrid").on("click", "tr", function (event) {
    var link = $(this).find('.view-icon');
    link.trigger('click');
    console.log(link);
});
```

and I want to trigger this

```
<table id="tableGrid">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='line-item-icons'>
                <i class='icon-view view-icon' data-url="${filePath}"></i>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but I receive this error:

***Failed to start loading***

How to solve this problem? The icon is inside the table.

Comment: I do not see any `table` or `tr`

Comment: I don't see any `id="tableGrid" in your html?

Comment: It would helpful to see it on a jsfiddle.

Comment: `Failed to start loading` doesn't sound like a jQuery error, which JS file is this error being thrown from?

Comment: Problem here is that when you click on **<tr>** it will call the click function as written in your jquery code which in turn again trigger the click event of the td by line **link.trigger('click');** code which bubbles up to tr and again triggers your **<tr>** click event and enter the infinite loop.

Comment: simply try `link.click();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out in your jquery.Hope this works

```
$("#tableGrid").on("click", "tr", function (event) {
  var link = $(this).find('.view-icon');
  link.trigger('click',link);
});
$('.view-icon').click(function(e,link){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(link);
});
```

Here only difference is that the link that you get in `console.log(link)` is element and not a jquery object. if you want it as a jquery object just wrap it as `console.log($(link))`

Answer (score 0):

Update your jQuery in this way -

```
$("#tableGrid tr").on("click", function (event) {
  var link = $(this).children('.view-icon');
  link.trigger('click');
  console.log(link);
});
```